# What preposition is used with "aufwachen"?

Tags: grammar, preposition, style

> 1. Ich wachte bei dem Anrufen des Kindes auf.
> 2. Ich wachte wegen des Anrufens des Kindes auf.

I'd like to say:

> I woke up to the calling of the baby.

Which preposition is correct here?

Comment: "Anrufen" means "to call *on the phone*" (or, in a religious context, "to call out to a god"). You picked the wrong translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual preposition used with *"aufwachen"* is ***von***:

> *von etwas (Dat.) aufwachen*.

Depending on the situation we may also use ***an***, ***bei***, ***aus***, ***durch***, or ***zu***:

Examples:

> Ich wachte **vom** Schreien des Babys auf.
>   Sie wachte **am** Weinen ihres Kindes auf.
>   Schon **beim** ersten Schrei des Babys wachte er auf.
>   Die Eltern wachten **aus** ihrem Mittagsschlaf auf, als das Kind sie rief.
>   Ich wurde **durch** das Schreien eines Babys aufgeweckt.
>   Ich wachte **zum** Klang einer wunderschönen Melodie auf.

Note that in German babies can do not much more than *weinen*, or *schreien*. Only at the time they are able to speak we may also use *rufen*.

Comment: Ähemm .... hast du schon mal Windeln bei einem deutschen Baby gewechselt?

Comment: @Ingo: ah ja - das nennt man dann *"brüllen"* ;)

Comment: I think "durch" is also not unheard of. Also, if the noise is only so much as accompanying the awakening without necessarily causing it, "bei" and "zu" can work too.

Comment: Danke, @Emanuel! Mir fällt im Moment kein passendes Beispiel mit *zu* ein... hast du eins parat?

Comment: Ich wachte zu den Klängen von Mozarts 2534. Konzert auf.